# Visual Studio C++ Check if class has a base

Tags: visual-c++, member, super, base-class

I would like to know if there is a way in Visual Studio C++ to check (from within a method) if a class has a base with a specific base-member in it. The method **Foo()** in the code below illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish.

I tried using **__if_exists()** and **__super**, but it doesn't seem to work.  Any advice would be appreciated.

The method **Foo()** is the same for **A** (base) and **B** (derived). That's because the initial idea was to add this method using a macro without distinguishing between base and derived classes.

```
class A {
    public:
        bool Foo() {
            __if_exists(__super::Foo) {
                return __super::Foo();
            }
            __if_not_exists(__super::Foo) {
                return false;
            }
    }
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        bool Foo() {
            __if_exists(__super::Foo) {
                return __super::Foo();
            }
            __if_not_exists(__super::Foo) {
                return false;
            }
    }
};
```

Comment: Isn't that precisely what inheritance and function overriding does?

Comment: It might. But I'm still curious if what I asked is somehow possible. The combination of __if_exists and __super at least seemed to indicate the possibility.

Comment: Standard C++ has `std::is_base_of`, but that's as far as this kind of type reflection gets, I think.